# Unable to type Arabic in in CKEditor 4.3

Tags: ckeditor

I need a Arabic language plug in into [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) that I have mentioned below.

*The optional language plugin, introduced in CKEditor 4.3, implements the WCAG 3.1.2 language of parts specification.*

Here is a sample link below:
http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/language.html

[CKEditor Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryTyz.png)

I am unable to figure out why I am unable to type Arabic in CKEditor. Although the sample clearly shows that there are three portions in different languages, is there anything necessary that I am not used or ignoring by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any plugin, you just need to set the text direction in the configuration of the CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('your_id', {
    contentsLangDirection: "rtl"
});
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7gb1m4g8/

NOTE: as per the [contentsLangDirection documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsLangDirection), you do not need to force this setting if the current UI language is already Arabic (it should be the case on computers with current language set to Arabic provided that the language is available in your instance of CKEditor):

> '' (an empty string) – Indicates that content direction will be the
>   same as either the editor UI direction or the page element direction
>   depending on the editor type

EDIT: the [Language](https://ckeditor.com/addon/language) plugin is only useful if you want to be able to have several paragraphs with different text directions.

If you really want to use this plugin, make sure you use the "Add to my editor" button from the [plugin page](https://ckeditor.com/addon/language), so that you can download a version of the CKEditor with all the required dependencies (the [Language](https://ckeditor.com/addon/language) plugin is dependent on the [MenuButton](https://ckeditor.com/addon/menubutton) plugin). Else, you may also [download the full preset](https://ckeditor.com/builder) of the ckeditor, which already includes all the plugins you need.

Comment: you mean to say! if i want to type Arabic or some other language then i also have to download that language keyboard on operating system.

Comment: Thanks @Gyum! your answer is helpful.

Comment: I think that if your current language settings are set to Arabic on your computer, CKEditor should default to Arabic UI and Right-to-left direction automatically. Make sure that you have downloaded the Arabic languages packs for the CKEditor too. If you found my answer helpful, don't forget to up vote it:) Thanks!

Comment: yup! it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [Language](https://ckeditor.com/addon/language) plugin inserts the `lang` attribute. To find out what the Language plugin may be used for, please see this link: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why

> I am unable to figure out why I am unable to type Arabic in CKEditor.

This can't be controlled with JavaScript. If you want to type in Arabic or English, you need to change keyboard settings and/or layout in your operating system. Please see: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10 and https://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10

Comment: I think your answer make sense, but this link make me confuse
https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsLanguage

Comment: although your answer is correct, but for me that answer is more easy to understand that's why i accept, but it does not means your answer is wrong bro! keep calm

Comment: i give you up vote as a feedback, receives you as my reputation goes up.

Comment: @AhmadHassan  is there any support for ckeditor till now, we write in English keyboard and Arabic can be written without Arabic keyboard in CKeditor.